# A for loop using colons

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm studying code and I don't understand what the for loop is actually doing.

```
for (final Move move : this.getPossibleMoves(color)) { 
      // do something..
}
```

Class Move:

```
public class Move {
private final int source;
private final int target;

public Move() {
    source = 0;
    target = 0;
}
```

getPossibleMoves method:

```
public Move[] getPossibleMoves(final PieceColor color) {
    // do something
    return simpleMoves.toArray(new Move[0]);
}
```

Comment: [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **for** statement has this form:

```
form(Type element: iterable) { ... }
```

where `element` is an element of an array, list, set or any collection of objects that are contained in an object of type `Iterable`.

in your case `getPossibleMoves()` is returning an array of objects of type `Move`. This is your code in a clearer way so you understand better what it does:

```
Move[] moves = this.getPossibleMoves(color);


for (final Move move : moves) { 

    // do something....

}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [the official docs on the **For-Each Loop**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) for explanation.

You can think about it this way:

```
for (Iterator<Move> itr = this.getPossibleMoves(color).iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
{
   final Move mv = itr.next();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), introduced with the *Java SE platform* in **version 5.0**, It is a simpler way of iterating over the elements of an array or `Collection`. They can be used when you wish to step through **each element of the array in first-to-last order**, and you do not need to know the index of the current element.

Assuming `this.getPossibleMoves(color)` returns a `Move[]` array.This code :

```
for (final Move move : this.getPossibleMoves(color)) { 
   // do something....
}
```

is implicitly equivalent to :

```
for (int index=0;index<this.getPossibleMoves(color).length;index++) { 
    final Move move = this.getPossibleMoves(color)[index];
   // do something....
}
```

**Suggested Reading:**

1. [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).
2. [Using Enhanced For-Loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)
3. [Enhanced for each loop iteration control](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000737.html)